# php ? url string not working with variable

Tags: php

I am using PHP to make different messages display (using `ècho`) depending on the `?` attached to the URL, like this: `http://somthing.com/page.php?something=1`. I attached a variable called `code` to the end of the URL: `http://somthing.com/page.php?code=1`.

```
      <?php
           $code;
            if(code == 1){ echo "Your account has been created."; 
            } else if(code == 2){
              echo "Thank you for your feedback.";
              if(isset($_POST["sent"])){
                echo "You will receive an email at " . $_POST["youremail"] . ".";
              }
            }


?>
```

I declared the variable on line 1. No message is displaying. What am I doing wrong here?
[Page the php is on.](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/contact)

Comment: I think you need to use a $_GET variable rather than just $code.  

    `$code=$_GET['code'];`

Comment: $ sign is missing on line 3

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code.  Not the least of which is an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @David, what's XSS? I'm kind of new to php.

Comment: what does this have anything to do with a contact page? Your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30357950/ is clearly connected to it, being account creation. Plus, it seems like you're just starting off with account creations. I'm really really hoping that you're using prepared statements and a safe password hashing method, otherwise and I can guarantee it, that you will get hacked, as will your users' accounts.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I have no users accounts, so there are no accounts to get hacked. Also, the other question you note was made after I asked this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should set $_GET['code'] to $code variable
- You should add $ sign when using a variable

---

**Fixed Code:**

```
$code = isset( $_GET['code'] ) ? $_GET['code'] : 0;
if ( $code == 1 ) {
    echo "Your account has been created.";
} else if ( $code == 2 ) {
    echo "Thank you for your feedback.";
    if ( isset( $_POST["sent"] ) ) {
        echo "You will receive an email at " . $_POST["youremail"] . ".";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data from $_GET

Something like this:

```
$code = $GET["code"];
```