# php $_POST[] not getting values

Tags: php

I am using PHP to send an email to myself when a user makes an account. it contains the username, password, and email:

```
<?php
    $code = isset( $_GET['code'] ) ? $_GET['code'] : 0;
if ( $code == 1 ) {
    echo "Your account has been created.";

   $master_to = "email@gmail.com";
   $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $master_user = $_POST["username"];
   $master_password = $_POST["password"];
   $master_ema = $_POST["mail"];
   $info = "Username:" .  $user . " Password: " . $password . " Email: " . $ema; 
   mail($master_to, "User Request", $info, $headers); 


   $a_to = $_POST["mail"];
   $a_message = '<h3 style="font-size:30pt; font-family:impact, fantasy; border:5px solid gray; color:green; border-radius:3px; background: linear-gradient(blue, gray); padding:15px;">SarkellianCreed.com</h3><br><br><br><p style="font-family:calibri, sans-serif; padding:20px;">Welcome to SarkellianCreed.com! Click <a href="http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com/accountfinalstep">here</a> to confirm your account.</p><p style="font-family:calibri, sans-serif; padding:20px;">If the link doesn&apos;t open, paste this address into your browser bar: <input type="text" value="http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com/accountfinalstep"></p>';
   mail($a_to,"Account Confirmation | SarkellianCreed.com", $a_message, $headers);








} else if ( $code == 2 ) {
    echo "Thank you for your feedback, " . $_POST["name"] . ".";
    if ( isset( $_POST["sent"] ) ) {
        echo "You will receive an email at " . $_POST["youremail"] . ".";
    }
}


?>
```

The page is also used for other usages, which is what the `else if($code == 2){}` is doing. The page is [here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/account.php)
When a user creates an account, the username, password, and email are supposed to show up in the textboxes, but nothing shows up. I used to use [this](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/confirm_account.php) to do the job. It didn't work either.

Comment: *"it contains the username, password"* <= this isn't safe at all.

Comment: You are sending your users passwords to *your* e-mail? Wow.

Comment: I hate to receive welcome register emails with my password inside.

Comment: @zairwolf That's okay, it's not going to you ;-)

Comment: I choose to not helping to develop these kind of websites

Comment: This question is asking for help in writing malicious software, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Another sidenote: The ideal thing to do here, is to instruct them to keep their password in a "safe" place. If they lose their password, then use a password resetting method. What you're doing is very unsafe and I hope for the love and security of your users, that you're using a state-of-the-art password hashing method, such as `password_hash()`. If you are, then I hope you're not keeping a copy of their password in a seperate place.

Comment: Plus, your login page also uses a GET method. This will pass the username **and** password right in the open world of hackers in an open URL. You really need to rethink this and use a POST method instead. I honestly wish you all the best of luck.

Comment: @MartinCarney, this is malicious software? How?

Comment: @yak613 If it's sending you its users' passwords in plain text, you are using it to steal private information from your users. If that's not your intent, you need to seriously redesign your program.

Comment: Considering that this site is mostly a hobby, and I haven't got a single email about an account from it since I made it, I don't think anyone is going to be affected. But just to be on the safe side, I got rid of the whole thing. [Here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com) is the homepage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should $_POST be set? You're using GET:

```
<form  id="ffresult_sbox0" ...snip... method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"...
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I see you went and fetched their page. I hope you didn't sign up too ;-)

Comment: nope. hit page, view source, ran in the other direction.

Comment: I didn't think so ;-)

Comment: @MarcB But why did you answer in the first place?

Comment: You should check out their other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30307489/ and a particular comment I've left them in there. It's almost a *sure fire bet*, that that's what's going to happen. *Scary*. Plus, why isn't there a green ticky here yet? Or, have we scared them off?

Comment: @MarcB, that's the wrong form you're looking at. It's from [FreeFind](http://freefind.com).

Comment: @yak613 That's where **you're wrong**. I too visited that link, which today doesn't exist along with the other link in your question, and it/they specifically contained a GET method. Trying to make a monkey out of Marc or anyone else for that matter, isn't very funny, nor a good idea.